# How to get a reference to the selected object in an Office Add-in

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I'm creating an Office Add-in for PowerPoint (desktop and online) that essentially adds custom navigation to objects, similar to hyperlinks.  I'd like to get a reference to the currently selected object and then expose a UI for the user to enter navigation details, which are then persisted via the `document.settings` API.

I can register for the `documentSelectionChanged` event, but the object passed to the handler only provides a reference to the event type and document.

```
Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync('documentSelectionChanged', onDocumentSelectionChanged);
```

I'm assuming I need to then query for the selection using `getSelectedDataAsync()`, but there doesn't appear to be a `CoercionType` enum value for something like a PowerPoint shape object.

Is it possible to obtain a serializable reference to the current object?

Comment: getSelectedDataAsync is not supported for the shape object. (if you wanted the text of the object, you could use Text coercion type.) The product team would like some clarification on what you want to do. It seems that you want to associate navigation info with an object and store it in a setting. What would be the key of the setting? How would an end user make use of the object to navigate?

Comment: The approach was intended to store the path to a target document and slide ID, along with data for future requirements.  When an end user clicked a decorated object, the add-in would perform the navigation.

We've since revised this to use simple hyperlinks.  However, I'm unable to leverage the wdSlideId querystring parameter or force slideshow view when using a link to the O365 PowerPoint web viewer.  I'll create a separate question for this.